# Matlab: errorbar figure with missing interval values

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, errorbar

I have a vector of [1,2,5,10] with its error ranges for each these 4 points. To plot the errorbar in matlab, I compute the midvalues of each these 4 ranges and computed its difference from the max value of that range to get error bar length.

I am trying to plot it as:

```
x=[1,2,5,10];
xup=[70,52,,50,36];
xlow=[40,30,20,20];
errorbar(midvalues,error) # midvalues are computed manually as (70+40)/2     
etc and err as 70-midvalue
```

This plots 4 points back to back on x axis as [1,2,3,4]. But since these points correspond to locations [1,2,5,10]. I want this to be reflected in the graph (not by changing labels for 3 and 4 locations). But I could not find a way to do so.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please see [mre]. I'm unclear as to what you want. You have 4 values, which represent x-axis locations, and errors associated to them, but no y values. Is that right?

Comment: I want to show in plot that at every value of x..the range of values obtained. The middle points of each x point range connected by line.This range I have shown in xup and xlow. I felt that errorbar kind of plot is suitable to show this. But errorbar plots it as 4 consecutive values.  I want the x axis to show gap between 2 and 5. and then 5 and 10.

Comment: So... from the doc... `errorbar(x,y,err) plots y versus x and draws a vertical error bar at each data point.`

Comment: As for the minimal reproducible example. I have given exact code and values. I am using.

Comment: Your code is not valid MATLAB code.